# Mobile Inventorty Manager Woocommerce API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Currently we are using [Scanventory](http://scanventory.net/) [mobile app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.raloco.qrcode1) as our mobile stock manager, but we are not too happy with it. Since their mobile application is not so nice we were wondering if there is any `API` out there which we can use in order to develop our own app.

We tried to search for another solutions but with no luck until now.

Currently we created an app that goes trough the Scanventory interface. But now every time we try to edit a product amount the Scanventory is converting this product to "Out of stock" so we need to reset the product from the product manager in Woocommerce.

Any help will be appreciated!

Best regards,

Dimitar Georgiev

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/ us this plugin it's really helpful for you

Comment: Thank you for the information can you put the comment as answer since  we go really good ideas from it how to solve our problem?